# android developer console - android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, layout, resources

I am new in android. I developed a game and it works well. But when i published my app to play store, i see some locks in the developer console. I checked developer console and i saw some problems like below. Below error gives some mobile phones (S6 edge, note 5 etc.)

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 

  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue (ResourcesImpl.java:202)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser (Resources.java:2970)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout (Resources.java:1986)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:425)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:378)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView (PhoneWindow.java:454)
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView (Activity.java:2548)


    at mypackagename.GameActivity.onCreate (GameActivity.java:193)

  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6955)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1126)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2927)
```

And here is my code between 188 and 200 lines

```
if (sWidth > 480 && screenInches >= 4 && screenInches <= 5) {
//          
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_4x);
        } else if (screenInches >= 5 && screenInches <= 6.5) {
//      
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_5x); 193.line is here
        } else if (screenInches > 6.5 && screenInches < 9) {
//          
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_7x);
        } else {
//          
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        }
```

I understand that " R.layout.activity_game_5x " could not find. But it's in my res folder. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are often issues with android studio and ressources... the best method I can provide you is to try to clean your solution, then rebuild it, and then rebuild the gradle file. If it doesn't work, I don't know what to do next

Comment: It works when i build in android studio, and also works good some mobile phones. There is no error. But my friend has Samsung S6 edge plus. He run my app and then its stopped.

Comment: could be a compatibility problem, what is the minimum required version of Android needed in your build ?

Comment: minSdkVersion="17" , targetSdkVersion="23". These are same in manifest and gradle files.

Comment: API 23 is for android 6.0 marshmallow... setting the minimum sdk to API 17 isn't enough sometimes to garantee the compatibility, if the famous samsoung s6 run under API 22 or older (lolipop), it may not work